# How can you extract the counts and percentages from the tableone package in R into separate variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a lot of large tables in R created using the tableone package. I was just asked to provide the tables in excel format as well with the counts and percentages (or mean/SD, etc.) in separate columns. Is there an easy way to extract this information from a tableone object? Saving the tableone output as a data frame that I could manipulate with dplyr would also work.

Example code for existing table format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tableone)
library(htmlTable)
starwars_data <- starwars %>%
mutate(species_cat = ifelse(species == 'Human', 'Human', 'Nonhuman'))
starwars_tbl <- CreateTableOne(vars = c('height', 'mass', 'hair_color', 'eye_color'), strata = 'species_cat', data = starwars_data)
starwars_tbl_print <- print(starwars_tbl, showAllLevels = TRUE, smd = TRUE, printToggle = FALSE)
htmlTable(starwars_tbl_print[, c(1:3,6)])
```

Desired output is a data frame with a structure something like the following image. Had to take a screenshot since it kept flagging my table as code that wasn't properly formatted, anyone know why?

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfEpZ.png)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Updated, thanks for the info.

Comment: Maybe `starwars_tbl$ContTable` and `summary(starwars_tbl$ContTable)` .

Comment: Thanks! ContTable and CatTable do what I need, but return a list rather than a dataframe and can't be converted to a dataframe. When I try as.data.frame, I get the error "cannot coerce class 'c("ContTable", "by")' to a data.frame". Is there a way to get the same data but in a data frame?

Comment: `mat <- print(starwars_tbl$ContTable)` gives a character matrix.